# Make Doxygen Warn If File Is Undocumented (With `\file` Tag)

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to configure to output a warning if a file is undocumented, meaning that the file does not use the `\file` tag to specify any documentation about the file itself.

The settings in my Doxyfile I believe to be somewhat relevant to this are as follows:

```
EXTRACT_ALL            = NO                                                                                                                                    
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES                                                                                                                                   
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES                                                                                                                                   
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES                                                                                                                                   
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES                                                                                                                                   
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO                                                                                                                                    
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = NO                                                                                                                                    

QUIET                  = YES                                                                                                                                   
WARNINGS               = YES                                                                                                                                   
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES                                                                                                                                   
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES                                                                                                                                   
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = YES                                                                                                                                   
WARN_AS_ERROR          = NO                                                                                                                                    
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"                                                                                                                  
WARN_LOGFILE           =
```

With these settings, I still do not receive warnings about missing `\file` documentation. Is there any way to have Doxygen produce these warnings?

Comment: Doxygen is in first instance meant for documenting function, classes, etc.and not for documenting files. There is no command / setting available to flag whether or not all files have been documented.

Comment: @albert As I understand it, doxygen does not document properly global variables present in a file if the file itself is not documented, so I think this is a valid request. Please clarify if I missed something.

Comment: The question was directed at documenting the file itself and my answer was regarding this. One can always do some external processing by means of e.g. `grep` (or similar on windows) to see which files do and which files don't have been documented (does just a plain `\file` mean commented or not or should there be at least one more line of explanation in the comment block. Global variables are mentioned as not documented as soon as the file is considered by doxygen to have information to be documented.

Comment: @albert, Thanks for the clarification. Disclosure, I am the maintainer of https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/ and we just do the same, grep to make sure files are documented. I wish there was a better way with doxygen itself complaining with a warning, like the OP, instead of external scripts.

Comment: @MarcAlff Maybe best to create an issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new (doxygen recently moved bug tracer from Bugzilla to Github!).