# How to check copyright statement header in files by Doxygen(Jenkins)?

Tags: jenkins, header, doxygen

I want to get similar warnings as below from doxygen but with this different that this warning need to inform about lack of statement header in file:

"NfcStack_Cfg.h:42: warning: missing title after \defgroup NfcStack_AppConfig"

I don't know if that is possible, maybe there is the more simplest way how to list files which don't have header statement on the beginning of file? I use Jenkins for compilation and task scanner which search only given phrase but I need to list of files which header statement are missing. Any idea?

Examples of header statement:

```
 *
 * @par Copyright
 * This code is the property of
 *
```

or

```
 *  COPYRIGHT
 *  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  \verbatim
 *  Copyright (c) 2022 by Company
 *
 *                This software is copyright protected and proprietary to Company.
 *
 *                All other rights remain with Company.
 *  \endverbatim
```

Option which enable described functionality in doxygen or other solution which resolve my issue.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Did you read the `\copyright` command?

Comment: Doxygen 1.9.6 - Yes, I readed but I want to get some warning from Doxygen when copyright statement is missing in some file because I have problem with files with only the code without headers in. I dont know how I can catch or list these files. I thougth that Doxygen help me with this but I did not find any option according with this

Comment: I was found similar topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071228/make-doxygen-warn-if-file-is-undocumented-with-file-tag

Comment: As far as I know doxygen cannot help here (and in this case it is the copyright statement but the next user wnats ... etc.) but you could do a search as suggested in the similar topic you found.